# For-Loop broken within while loop

Tags: python, if-statement, break

Here's my code:

```
primes = [2, 3]

while len(primes) != 1001:
    a = primes[-1] + 2
    for i in primes:
        if a % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(primes)
        primes.append(a)

print(primes[1002])
```

This is supposed to create a list up to the 1001th prime number and then print the 1001th number. It starts by taking the last number in the list and adding 2, then checking if the given number is divisible by any of the members of the primes list. If it is divisible, the for-loop breaks and the else clause is skipped. If not, the number is appended to primes list. The process repeats until the list has a length of 1001. After the loop ends, the last number is printed.

The output, however, is the following:

```
[2, 3]
[2, 3, 5]
_
```

And the program is not terminated until manually doing so. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is incorrectly indented. Is that just in this post, or in your actual source?

Comment: Hu? It works just fine for me…

Comment: @Cal: It's not incorrectly indented- that `else` clause does belong with the `for`, not the `if`.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I misunderstood in which way the code was trying to do the wrong thing :)

Comment: just a tip, that `print(primes[1002])`, I think you're trying to print the last element in the list.  Instead you can use `print(primes[-1])` to get the last element

Answer (score 5):

This is because, in the case that `primes[-1] + 2` is not prime, no state is changed (so the program loops forever).

A better approach might be something like:

```
 from itertools import count

 primes = [2, 3]
 for a in count(5, step=2):
     for p in primes:
         if a % p == 0:
             break
     else:
         primes.append(a)
         if len(primes) > 1001:
             break
```

Comment: Indeed- in this case, when it reaches 9.

Comment: Thank you, that code does indeed work. However, what list does count(5, step=2) generate?

Comment: `count(5, step=2)` will create a generator which yield every odd number 5 and greater.

Answer (score 1):

The first non-prime `a` you hit, `a` stops growing. This works:

```
primes = [2, 3]

a = 3
while len(primes) != 1001:
    a += 2
    for i in primes:
        if a % i == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(primes) # I'm not sure why you'd want to do this
        primes.append(a)

print(primes[1000]) # Note the index: 1000, not 1002
```

Comment: Thank you. I did print(primes) afterwards, so I could see when does the list stop growing. (There was no output otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would caution against using == and != in while loops unless you can guarantee that the sentinel value will be reached.  You might want to use: *while len(primes) < 1000:* for example.

Similarly you need to sure that the exit condition of the loop will be reached eventually.

Another option would be to use *while True:* as the loop header and have some other handling with a break inside the loop.  (`if iteration_count > 1000000 or len(primes > 1000): break ... else iteration_count += 1` for example).

(Imagine some bug where more than one value got appended to the primes list in your example ... it could loop forever even if the rest of the code was correct --- millions of primes later the program crashes with out of memory).

The *else:* clauses on loops is a feature that's peculiar to Python.  In most other programming languages you have to create a sentinel variable and test its value after leaving the loop.  Think of the *else:* clause on loops as being specific for attempts to search for something ... and *else:* is the code executed if you did NOT find a suitable item in the loop.

Given that I'm not sure what you're really trying to do here.